# Flatten SOQL Subquery to return 1 row per ActivityHistory

Tags: python, subquery

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT (SELECT CallDurationInSeconds, CallData__c, Closed_After_DueDate__c,
    Reminder_Date_Time_LEX__c, PrimaryWhoId, Current_User_Assigned__c, LastModifiedById,
    Time_taken_to_Close_the_Task__c, Priority, Location, CallObject, OwnerId, IsAllDayEvent,
    AdCentralActivityId__c, Status, CallDisposition, Description, ActivitySubtype,
    LastModifiedDate, ActivityType, Original_Due_Date__c, Task_Closed_Date__c, Push_Counter__c,
    WhoId, WhatId, ActivityDate, CurrencyIsoCode, dnis__c, IsHighPriority, IsDeleted,
    AccountId, CallType, Call_Recording__c, EndDateTime, DurationInMinutes, IsVisibleInSelfService,
    CreatedById, StartDateTime, PrimaryAccountId, IsReminderSet, SFDC_Active__c, IsClosed,
    ReminderDateTime, SystemModstamp, CreatedDate, IsTask, AlternateDetailId, Id,
    Activity_Type__c FROM ActivityHistories WHERE SystemModstamp >= 2018-10-04T00:00:00Z
 and SystemModstamp
    < 2018-10-05T00:00:00Z
) FROM Account
```

Part of the code I already have, which works for all the other SOQL queries we have:

```
sf = Salesforce(security_token='token', username='uname', password='pwd', instance_url='https://company.my.salesforce.com')
result = sf.query(query_input)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result['records'])
df.drop('attributes', 1, inplace=True)
df['row_hash'] = df.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
```

However this will fail because the subquery returns a list of dictionaries. How could I return 1 record per row. I can't just query `ActivityHistories` directly, which is a shame.

Is there anyway in which I could **return the list of Activity Histories, omitting the Accounts**?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't process the response into a single list of ActivityHistory records before running the code you already have?  Not sure whether your use case won't allow for it for some reason.

Something like this:

```
List<Account> accts = ...your query here...
List<ActivityHistory> justHistories = new list<ActivityHistory>();

for(Account a : accts){
    for(ActivityHistory h : a.ActivityHistories){
        justHistories.add(h);
    }
}
```

If not, then no, there isn't a way to query ActivityHistory directly. It always needs to be within the context of the object you want the history for.

Comment: Yes there is a reason, the tooling I'm feeding the query is a black box and changing it would require a lot more time. If I could do the simplest of the changes, it would be literally a single line in python with a list comprehension:
`rows = [row['ActivityHistories']['records'] for row in results['records'] if row['ActivityHistories']]`. And I'm not using java for this project, as you can see the pandas code up there.

Comment: Ah -- I knew it couldn't be that simple  ;)   In that case, no, there isn't a way to query ActivityHistory directly. It always needs to be within the context of the Type you want the history for.  Sorry I couldn't give you better news.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.  (Also, just fyi, that's Apex -- Salesforce's proprietary programming language.  It is very similar to Java, as you noticed.)